# In Angular 5+ ngrx 5+ rxjs 5.5.6 using fromPromise in effects where the promise rejects - catchError doesn't work and promise error remains uncaught

Tags: promise, rxjs, ngrx, effects, unhandled

In Angular 5+ ngrx 5+ rxjs 5.5.6 using fromPromise in effects where the promise rejects - catchError doesn't work and promise error remains uncaught.

```
@Effect()
    public someAction: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(SomeAction.TYPE),
        mergeMap((action) => {
            let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject({ status: 401 }); });
            return fromPromise(p).pipe(
                map((response) => {
                    return new SuccessAction();
                }),
                catchError((err) => {
                    return of(new ErrorAction());
                })
            );
        })
    );
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this code? I followed all the guidelines I could find like:

1) https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/frompromise.html

2) https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effects

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in one of my resolvers, which returns Observable.throw(err) when using the effects result, which is not handled anywhere and results in this promise uncaught error.